# Inserting the elements of a list to the middle of another list

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I have a list like this:

```
["*****", "*****"]
```

I want to insert the elements of another list to the middle of this list like this:

```
["*****", "abc", "ded", "*****"]
```

However, my attempt produces a list nested inside another list:

```
["*****", ["abc", "ded"], "*****"]
```

This is my code:

```
def addBorder(picture):

    length_of_element = len(picture[0])
    number_of_asterisks = length_of_element + 2
    new_list = ['*' * number_of_asterisks for i in range(0, 2)]
    new_list.insert(len(new_list)//2, [value for value in picture])
    
    return new_list
```

I know that my code is good. I just want to know what tweaks I need to make.

Comment: No its not a duplicate.  I don't have trouble understanding slicing notation.  I want to append the elements of a list and not the entire list to the middle of another list.

Comment: Insert inserts ONE element at a position - not multiple. Slice the list: `newlist = oldlist[:half] + data + newlist[half:]`

Comment: Yea but `data` would do the exact same thing.  It would just add it as a list and not as individual elements.

Comment: list.insert() can't be used the way you want. You can insert all single elements in a loop - or slice the list. The dupe is the way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = ['****', '****']
b = ['abc', 'efg']
mid_index = len(a)//2 # Integer result for a division

result = a[:mid_index] + b + a[mid_index:]
```

If you want to assign the result to `a` directly, You can also simply:

```
a[mid_index:mid_index] = b
```

Comment: `mid_index = len(a) // 2` - why create a float and cast it?

Comment: @PatrickArtner You are right, changed it